# Cutting an image to a CALayers content during an animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, calayer, cgpath

I have created a subclass of CALayer to draw a slice of a pie chart with a custom color (`color`), a startAngle (`actualStartAngle`), an endAngle (`actualEndAngle`) and an image (`image`)[This image should always be in the middle of the slice] as animating this is not possible with a normal CAShapeLayer. The layer is currently drawn like this:

```
- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx{
    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, self.center.x, self.center.y);
    CGContextAddArc(ctx, self.center.x, self.center.y, self.radius, self.actualEndAngle, self.actualStartAngle, YES);

    CGContextClosePath(ctx);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, self.color);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 0);

    CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathFillStroke);

    if (self.image) {
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, [self getFrameForImgLayerWithStartAngle:self.actualStartAngle andEndAngle:self.actualEndAngle], self.image);
    }
}
```

These individual slices are animated by:

```
[CATransaction begin];

CABasicAnimation *colorAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"color"];
colorAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
colorAnimation.duration = duration;
colorAnimation.fromValue = (id)self.color;
colorAnimation.toValue = (id)colorTU.CGColor;

CABasicAnimation *startAngleAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"actualStartAngle"];
startAngleAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
startAngleAnimation.duration = duration;
startAngleAnimation.fromValue = [self valueForKey:@"actualStartAngle"];
startAngleAnimation.toValue = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:newStartAngle];

CABasicAnimation *endAngleAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"actualEndAngle"];
endAngleAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
endAngleAnimation.duration = duration;
endAngleAnimation.fromValue = [self valueForKey:@"actualEndAngle"];
endAngleAnimation.toValue = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:newEndAngle];

if (completionBlock) {
    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:completionBlock];
}

if (colorTU && colorTU.CGColor != self.color) {
    [self addAnimation:colorAnimation forKey:@"color"];
}
if (newStartAngle != self.actualStartAngle) {
    [self addAnimation:startAngleAnimation forKey:@"actualStartAngle"];
}
if (newEndAngle != self.actualEndAngle) {
    [self addAnimation:endAngleAnimation forKey:@"actualEndAngle"];
}

[CATransaction commit];
```

The problem is that I would like to have the image only take up the space that the individual layer takes up (resp. the shape in it). This is solved in general by this method:

```
- (BOOL)imageFitsIntoSliceWithStartAngle:(float)sA andEndAngle:(float)eA{
    BOOL fits = YES;
    CGRect rectToUse = [self getFrameForImgLayerWithStartAngle:sA andEndAngle:eA];

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:self.center];
    [path addArcWithCenter:self.center radius:self.deg startAngle:sA endAngle:eA clockwise:YES];
    for (int w = 0; w <= 1; w++) {
        if (fits) {
            for (int h = 0; h <= 1; h++) {
                if (![path containsPoint:CGPointMake(rectToUse.origin.x + rectToUse.size.width * w, rectToUse.origin.y + rectToUse.size.height * h)]) {
                    fits = NO;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return fits;
}
```

The problem now is that it may fit in the end and not at the beginning of the animation, so I would have to cut the image to be as big as the slice when this happens.

I have tried the following:

- set a mask for the slice instead of drawing it directly -> This is firstly bad coding and I have found it to be very energy inefficient, also it created an error (`expecting model layer not copy`) for me.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue? (not what I tried but this problem in general, I don't think you should do something like what I tried above)

Thanks

Comment: Sorry i don't have time to dig into your code, but do you try CGContextClipToMask ?

Comment: How I understand it, `CGContextClipToMask` is, even when it would work, very inefficient. I have basically 'solved' this issue by applying a mask to a separate imageLayer, but that is a really inefficient method and generates a hell of a lag. Drawing an image would be even more so, right?

Comment: wow, what size is your image ?

Comment: Well, I would have to redraw it with every frame and it is about 400x400 px, so on Retina (resp. Retina HD on 6 Plus with @3x) that is 800 resp. 1200 px running at 30 fps min. to seem smooth...

Comment: Oh ok. Seems pretty big indeed. Could you show me the image itself ?

Comment: Well it would either be an image of a pie chart or of an individual slice of a pie chart. This is actually pretty simple, but, of course, animations of these slices, especially with center-aligned images in them, are not completely fluid. With my method I have found it to be fluid for up to 3 slices, for 4 it's totally OK, but at 5 or higher it just lags the hell out of itself.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it'll help, but here the drawing code for a pie chart part :

```
- (void)drawChartWithFrame:(CGRect)frame startAngle:(CGFloat)startAngle endAngle:(CGFloat)endAngle fillColor:(UIColor *)fillColor strokeColor:(UIColor *)strokeColor
{

    //// Oval Drawing
    CGRect ovalRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame),CGRectGetMinY(frame), CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetHeight(frame));
    UIBezierPath* ovalPath = UIBezierPath.bezierPath;
    [ovalPath addArcWithCenter: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(ovalRect), CGRectGetMidY(ovalRect)) radius: CGRectGetWidth(ovalRect) / 2 startAngle: -(startAngle - 25) * M_PI/180 endAngle: -(endAngle - 93) * M_PI/180 clockwise: YES];
    [ovalPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(ovalRect), CGRectGetMidY(ovalRect))];
    [ovalPath closePath];ansform ovalTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(CGRectGetMidX(ovalRect), CGRectGetMidY(ovalRect));
    ovalTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(ovalTransform, 1, CGRectGetHeight(ovalRect) / CGRectGetWidth(ovalRect));
    [ovalPath applyTransform: ovalTransform];

    [fillColor setFill];
    [ovalPath fill];
    [strokeColor setStroke];
    ovalPath.lineWidth = 1;
    [ovalPath stroke];
}
```

It's much lighter to animate that a real image.

Comment: I am able to draw a piechart. What I am trying is to dynamically place an image (of anything [a house, a door, a person, an apple, anything ]) in the middle of each individual chart slice. Then I want to animate this and the image should logically only take up as much space as the slice and not overlap.